# Heroku: Update Node Version not working

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku, npm

I want to update my app node version deployed to Heroku
Currently it is 0.10.40 on Heroku app

To change to my desired version I mainpulated the package.json file as:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.8.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0"
  }
}
```

And then deployed my code to heroku app. But still while checking the version through heroku CLI

```
heroku run node -v -a myapp
```

the version is not updated and it is still using the older one.

Any help !

Comment: Why do you use `meteor run` on a production server? Are you using a buildpack to deploy your Meteor project on Heroku?

Comment: @ghybs Without defining meteor run how would I run my app on server.

Comment: And the main issue that I'm facing is that the node version on server isn't getting changed inspite of updating my package.json

Comment: ["you shouldn’t run your app in production by running the `meteor [run]` command"](https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html#dev-vs-prod)

Comment: You have not replied my 2nd question. Should you use a buildpack for Meteor on Heroku, that buildpack would automatically `meteor build` your project, which specifies the node version (bound by Meteor version).

Comment: @ghybs Actually I'm not sure about it in fact do not remember whether I had set a buildpack or not ... But currently the Heroku log of my deployment logs a line saying  "Default types for buildpack -> web"

Answer (score 4):

1. You should [*build*](http://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorbuild) your Meteor project to use it in production, [instead of](https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html#dev-vs-prod) relying on the same `meteor run` command that you use for development. You can also find details on the Meteor Guide for [Deployment](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html).
2. In the case of Heroku host, you can instead take advantage of a [*buildpack*](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) to automatically perform this build step on Heroku side, and avoid having to "commit" your build output. For Meteor, you can use [AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse](https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse) for example. Note that you will not be able to manually change the Node version yourself. It is automatically set by the Meteor version you are using in your project.
3. Still, by specifying the `"engines"` field in your `package.json` file and letting Heroku use your Meteor project as a Node.js app, it should have adjusted the Node version accordingly. But there are several potential mistakes that might explain why it is not. E.g. the new version of your `package.json` file [not being properly committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388338/heroku-does-not-read-node-version), etc. Your current question does not share enough details to tell more about what could be the exact reason.

Comment: Can you help in figuring out how to run meteor command on herkou wrt app specified

Comment: That should very probably be a different question. At first sight I do not think it is possible to run meteor commands, since meteor would not be installed.

Comment: It is installed ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094423/meteor-run-command-on-heorku-app

Answer (score 0):

for a windows user: 
First Uninstall the previous nodejs from Program Files then download and install latest node
https://nodejs.org/en/