# Meteor : Run command on Heroku app

Tags: meteor, heroku

I do have Meteor installed on my Heroku app. Due to some vulnerabilities concern Heroku is asking me to update Node.js version which is possible by updating the Meteor version as directed [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8903#issuecomment-314947249)

But how would I run the update on my heroku.
Currently I'm using command:

```
heroku run meteor update --release 1.5.1 -a myappname
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go to your Meteor project (repo) with your code editor, do the update, make sure everything runs ok on "local". A good opportunity to run "npm outdated" too and see if there is anything to do in that area, then push to production.

I am pretty sure you should not update Meteor via Heroku CLI or command line.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to update Meteor and Node version for Heroku aplication is given below:

[Update Node version for Meteor app deployed to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103109/update-node-version-for-meteor-app-deployed-to-heroku/)