# Heroku engines.node (package.json) unspecified

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I'm having a problem with pushing my codes to Heroku.
package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engine": {
    "node": "12.16.2",
    "npm": "6.13.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.20",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "backend": "nodemon server/index.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

output

```
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.16.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.13.4
<!-- more stuff -->
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > my-app@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_016788c07037e47ee5638bf5c1b1f631
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:
remote:        Could not find a required file.
remote:          Name: index.html
remote:          Searched in: /tmp/build_016788c07037e47ee5638bf5c1b1f631/public
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.yXjxR/_logs/2020-04-11T07_16_57_245Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

As you can see even though I specified my node and npm version in `package.json` Heroku is not recognising it and my push is rejected. I tried to make a ticket on the Heroku website but since this is a free application they did not allow me to ask on their helpline.

*edit* 
I upgraded the npm and node version to the default by Heroku but I get the error `Could not find a required file.Name: index.html`

Comment: can you check if this helps: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388338/heroku-does-not-read-node-version)

Comment: @Tshiteej Hey, I made some edits on my code. Basically I upgraded the node and npm version to Heroku's default after testing the link you send, but now I'm still getting errors.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Looks like Heroku doesn't support 12.16.2 yet. try with 12.16.1 in package.json engine section.

change this

"engine": {
    "node": "12.16.2",
    "npm": "6.13.4"
  },

to

"engines": {
    "node": "12.16.1",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  },

Comment: Update: heroku now supports 12.16.2 . please note the engines vs engine in your package.json.

Answer (score 0):

For deploying your app successfully. You should first create a specific file inside the root of your project's folder and the name of that file must be.

> Procfile

without any extra extension. the content of Procfile file must be `web: node index.js` or whatever your main file is. don't use `web: node run index.js` just `web: node index.js` is ok.

Answer (score 0):

my package.json didnt have
"engines" specified

adding
"engines": { "node": "12.16.1", "npm": "6.14.4" },
in my package.json fixed it