# react app with tailwind deploying issue heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, tailwind-css

heroku says

```
   added 1605 packages, and audited 1606 packages in 15s
   
   223 packages are looking for funding
     run `npm fund` for details
   
   6 high severity vulnerabilities
   
   To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
     npm audit fix --force
   
   Run `npm audit` for details.
```

-----> Build
Running build

```
   > frontend@0.1.0 build
   > react-scripts build
   
   Creating an optimized production build...
   Failed to compile.
   
   static/css/main.a8ac7e21.css from Css Minimizer plugin
   /tmp/build_e79f02b1/static/css/main.a8ac7e21.css:2532:73: Unknown word [webpack://./src/index.css:3,0][static/css/main.a8ac7e21.css:2532,73]
```

-----> Build failed

```
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   Some possible problems:
   
   - Node version not specified in package.json
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
   
   Love,
   Heroku
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
!     Push failed

here is my code
https://github.com/sardor1215/test/tree/master

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku does not read node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388338/heroku-does-not-read-node-version)

Answer (score 0):

try to specify node engine in your package.json 
for example

```
"engines": {
  "node": "14.17.5"
}
```

better try to use the same version that on your locale machine 
link to heroku help: https://help.heroku.com/6235QYN4/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-no-matching-node-versions